# Pandas subtraction for multiindex pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a following data frame which I converted to pandas pivot table having two indexes "Date" and "Rating.
The values are sorted in columns A, B and C.

[image: Pivot data]

I would like to find a solution which will subtract the values for each column and rating for consecutive days. Say, the change in A from 03/01/2007 to 02/01/2007 for rating M would be `0.4179 - 0.4256 = -0.0077`. The subtraction won't always be performed on a one day difference. But it will always be  the (new date - the old date).

The results I'm looking for can be found in the table below:

[image]

Comment: Did you try `df.sort_values('Date').groupby('Rating')[['A', 'B', 'C']].diff().fillna(0)`?

Comment: No, and honestly don't know why. Thank you! Simple and beautiful. Works perfectly, I was fighting with "for" loops before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataframe is correctly sorted (or use `df.sort_values('Date')`), you can use `groupby_diff`:

```
# Replace ['A'] with ['A', 'B', 'C']
df['A_diff'] = df.groupby('Rating')['A'].diff().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Date Rating       A  A_diff
0  02/01/2007      M  0.4256  0.0000
1  02/01/2007     MM  0.4358  0.0000
2  02/01/2007    MMM  0.4471  0.0000
3  03/01/2007      M  0.4179 -0.0077
4  03/01/2007     MM  0.4325 -0.0033
5  03/01/2007    MMM  0.4476  0.0005
6  04/01/2007      M  0.4173 -0.0006
7  04/01/2007     MM  0.4316 -0.0009
8  04/01/2007    MMM  0.4469 -0.0007
```

If you don't know how many columns you have, you can try:

```
cols = df.columns[2:]
df[cols] = df.groupby('Rating')[cols].diff().fillna(0)
```

Comment: Perfect. What if I add a modification to the column numbers? Say, I don't know how many columns would there be. It might be 'A', 'B' only or 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' and I don't want to change it manually every time.

Comment: Try with `df.columns[2:]` instead of `A`.